# Haskell generics with unique ids

Tags: generics, haskell, types, functional-programming

I've been using Uniplate for a while, but I find the lack ability to identify a node to make things more difficult for me. Is there a generics implementation that allows absolute ids? Here is an example of some APIs I would expect such an implementation to have:

```
universe :: (Data on) => on -> [(Id,on)] -- returns all sub nodes, with ids
children :: (Data on) => on -> [(Id,on)] -- returns all direct children, with ids
transformAbove :: (Data on) => (on -> on) -> Id -> on -> on -- applies a transformation to all nodes which are ancestors of the node with the given id
```

Comment: Interesting idea! The only help I can give you is to look at the `data-reify` package, if you'd like to build it yourself.

Comment: What would you expect the type and value of `Id` to be?

Comment: I would expect `Id ~ [Int]`, although if we know the maximal branching B of D in advance, we can also have `Id ~ Int` and have each child id equal to `parent id * B + child index`

Comment: ok, for the single scalar, it would be better to use Integer over Int since the id grows exponentially to tree depth

Answer (score 1):

Here's at least a partial solution of the first two functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Main where
import Text.Show.Pretty

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data

type Id = [Int]

indexed :: Data on => on -> [(Int, on)]
indexed tree = zip [0..] $ children tree

labeled :: Data on => on -> [(Id, on)]
labeled tree = ([], tree) : [ (x:xs, tree) | (x, subtree) <- indexed tree, (xs, tree)
                                                          <- labeled subtree ]

universeI :: Data on => on -> [(Id, on)]
universeI = labeled

childrenI :: Data a => a -> [(Id, [a])]
childrenI = labeled . children
```

For a binary tree this we can apply childrenI:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Fork (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data, Typeable)

a :: Tree Int
a = Fork (Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Fork (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4))

main = print $ childrenI a
```

And get the following labelings:

```
[ ( [] , Fork (Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Fork (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4)) )
, ( [ 0 ] , Fork (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2) )
, ( [ 0 , 0 ] , Leaf 1 )
, ( [ 0 , 1 ] , Leaf 2 )
, ( [ 1 ] , Fork (Leaf 3) (Leaf 4) )
, ( [ 1 , 0 ] , Leaf 3 )
, ( [ 1 , 1 ] , Leaf 4 )
]
```

Comment: Are there no existing packages for this sort of thing?

Comment: No, this isn't normally something that a generics library would provide, as it really only makes sense in tree like structures. If you need this functionality you can implement it on top of either Uniplate or SYB.